# Intellisense в VisualStudio 2008

Tags: xaml, visual-studio, c#

Проблема заключается в следующем: при работе с большими текстовыми файлами(xaml разметка) возникают зависания VS, думаю, что проблема в обновлении Intellisense.

Скажите, как отключить Intellisense в VisualStudio 2008 или, возможно, как то изменить ее настройки для решения проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

"Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\feacp.dll" - попробуйте удалить(отбакапить) этот файл для Visual C++ это убивает Intellisense.